# PHP5-ldap and LDAPS under Apache2 (not working) vs CLI (working)

Tags: php, linux, apache2, ldap

I'm trying to connect to an LDAPS server using Apache2, PHP5.3, with the php5-ldap package.

When I set the code off using PHP-CLI, it works fine.

When I execute the same code under Apache2, the bind always fails.

I've set TLS_REQCERT to NEVER, hence the CLI version working.

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
<?php

   // using anonymous ldap bind
   // connect to ldap server
   $ldapconn = ldap_connect("ldaps://XXX.XXX.com")
       or die("Could not connect to LDAP server.");

   if ($ldapconn)
   {
       // binding anonymously
       $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn) or die("Couldn't bind\n");

       if ($ldapbind) {
           echo "LDAP anonymous bind successful...";
       } else {
           echo "LDAP anonymous bind failed...";
       }
   }

   $res = ldap_search($ldapconn, 'ou=XXX,o=XXX', '(sn=XXX*)');
   $info = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $res);

   echo "<pre>" . var_dump($info) . "</pre>";

   ldap_unbind($ldapconn);

?>
```

Comment: Please post:  
*  code example
*  error message
*  Why do you mention TLS_REQCERT, is your cert self-signed?

Comment: See below for code. When run from the command line al is dandy. When accessed through Apache2 it borks with 'Couldn't bind '

Comment: Do you run that in the command line of the same apache server?

Comment: I'm having this same problem. It doesn't seem to make any sense. The only difference is that I'm using CentOS 6. Of key importance, we are doing Apache authentication/negotiation with the AD server--I'm not sure if that matters but it seems to be need-to-know information.

Comment: Have you tried using ldap_error($ldapconn) It should contain a clue as to what the error generated by bind was. My guess is that it could be related to either a global not being set, or a difference between your CLI php.ini and your apache php.ini (assuming they differ).

Answer (score 0):

Review php.ini, and make sure the ext is being loaded with phpinfo(). Differint sapi's might try loading php.ini from differint locations, so also check the location of php.ini within phpinfo() and make sure it's loading the one your expecting.